# Wordpress: Add Menu Page -> Custom Posts

Tags: wordpress, menu, admin, posts

So I'm creating a small plugin for Wordpress that will require a custom menu page on the dashboard admin sidebar. I created the function that creates the page and menu with the icon, but realized that it will actually need to be set up like the Posts or Pages menu items where you have the option of switching out the featured image/video. 
So it would have the option to see the list of created "posts" or add a new one. I've tried to find a tutorial that at least describes where to go in the codex that describes this, but I'm not finding a tutorial or a location in the Wordpress codex that describes creating something like a "post" or "pages" menu/with the needed sub menus. I would appreciate it if anyone could share a tutorial for this if they found one or the location for this in the Wordpress codex if the actually know its direct location? Thanks!

Comment: Do you know about [Custom Post Types](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Post_Types)? For what you're saying, I understand that this is exactly what you need.

Comment: So you want to add your custom posts to the menu?

Comment: mathielo, okay I think that is indeed what I am looking for. Thank you very much for this!